# How to group a javascript object array by multiple of its properties?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, grouping

I want to convert `showtimesData` to `showtimesByLocationByDate`
Any idea how to do it without using any third party library and just using pure javascript? Otherwise, what third party library can I use for this?

```
    var showtimesData = [
        {"location":"location1", "date":"31-12-2016", "time":"1:00"},
        {"location":"location1", "date":"31-12-2016", "time":"2:00"},
        {"location":"location1", "date":"01-01-2017", "time":"3:00"},
        {"location":"location1", "date":"01-01-2017", "time":"4:00"},
        {"location":"location2", "date":"31-12-2016", "time":"1:00"},
        {"location":"location2", "date":"31-12-2016", "time":"2:00"},
        {"location":"location2", "date":"01-01-2017", "time":"3:00"},
        {"location":"location2", "date":"01-01-2017", "time":"4:00"},
    ];
    var showtimesByLocationByDate = [
        {
            "location":"location1",
            "dates":[
                {
                    "date":"31-12-2016",
                    "times":["1:00","2:00"]
                },
                {
                    "date":"01-01-2017",
                    "times":["3:00","4:00"]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "location":"location2",
            "dates":[
                {
                    "date":"31-12-2016",
                    "times":["1:00","2:00"]
                },
                {
                    "date":"01-01-2017",
                    "times":["3:00","4:00"]
                }
            ]
        },
    ];
```

Comment: Does it have to follow that specific format? Date lookup would be much faster if it'd be a property of an object.

Comment: if I were to set the dates as properties, can I loop through the properties to get the dates as strings?

Comment: Yes, it's possible to loop through the properties of the object.

Comment: I did some googling, is it using Object.keys function?

Answer (score 4):

This proposal features just [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) with one temporary object for referencing the array items.

```js
var showtimesData = [{ "location": "location1", "date": "31-12-2016", "time": "1:00" }, { "location": "location1", "date": "31-12-2016", "time": "2:00" }, { "location": "location1", "date": "01-01-2017", "time": "3:00" }, { "location": "location1", "date": "01-01-2017", "time": "4:00" }, { "location": "location2", "date": "31-12-2016", "time": "1:00" }, { "location": "location2", "date": "31-12-2016", "time": "2:00" }, { "location": "location2", "date": "01-01-2017", "time": "3:00" }, { "location": "location2", "date": "01-01-2017", "time": "4:00" }, ],
    showtimesByLocationByDate = showtimesData.reduce(function (r, a) {
        var o;
        if (!(a.location in r.obj)) {
            o = { location: a.location, dates: [] };
            r.obj[a.location] = { dates: o.dates };
            r.array.push(o);
        }
        if (!(a.date in r.obj[a.location])) {
            o = { date: a.date, times: [] };
            r.obj[a.location].dates.push(o);
            r.obj[a.location][a.date] = o.times;
        }
        r.obj[a.location][a.date].push(a.time);
        return r;
    }, { array: [], obj: {} }).array;

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(showtimesByLocationByDate, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Bonus: Generic version with a given data structure

```js
var showtimesData = [{ "location": "location1", "date": "31-12-2016", "time": "1:00" }, { "location": "location1", "date": "31-12-2016", "time": "2:00" }, { "location": "location1", "date": "01-01-2017", "time": "3:00" }, { "location": "location1", "date": "01-01-2017", "time": "4:00" }, { "location": "location2", "date": "31-12-2016", "time": "1:00" }, { "location": "location2", "date": "31-12-2016", "time": "2:00" }, { "location": "location2", "date": "01-01-2017", "time": "3:00" }, { "location": "location2", "date": "01-01-2017", "time": "4:00" }, ],
    structure = [
        { key: 'location', data: 'dates' },
        { key: 'date', data: 'times' },
        { key: 'time' }
    ],
    showtimesByLocationByDate = showtimesData.reduce(function (r, a) {
        var properties = structure.slice(),
            lastKey = properties.pop().key;

        properties.reduce(function (rr, b) {
            var o = {},
                p = {},
                key = b.key,
                value = a[key],
                array = b.data;

            if (!(value in rr.obj)) {
                o[key] = value;
                o[array] = [];
                p[array] = o[array];
                rr.obj[value] = p;
                rr.array.push(o);
            }
            return { array: rr.obj[value][array], obj: rr.obj[value] };
        }, r).array.push(a[lastKey]);

        return r;
    }, { array: [], obj: {} }).array;

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(showtimesByLocationByDate, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: You answer is very precise, but I was just wondering is there a way to make it more generic?

Comment: @Rajesh, it depends on the data structure and how generic it should be.

Comment: I was just wondering if we could make a function where we pass data and property to group by, and it returns a grouped value. Following is the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/sktkjpno/) that I have tries yet.

Answer (score 4):

I'd propose this transformation:

```js
var showtimesData = [
        {"location":"location1", "date":"31-12-2016", "time":"1:00"},
        {"location":"location1", "date":"31-12-2016", "time":"2:00"},
        {"location":"location1", "date":"01-01-2017", "time":"3:00"},
        {"location":"location1", "date":"01-01-2017", "time":"4:00"},
        {"location":"location2", "date":"31-12-2016", "time":"1:00"},
        {"location":"location2", "date":"31-12-2016", "time":"2:00"},
        {"location":"location2", "date":"01-01-2017", "time":"3:00"},
        {"location":"location2", "date":"01-01-2017", "time":"4:00"},
    ];
  
var transformed = showtimesData.reduce(function(obj, show){
  //var { location, date, time } = show; //if destructuring is available
  var location = show.location,
      date = show.date,
      time = show.time,
      objLocation = obj[location] = obj[location] || { dates : { } },
      dates = objLocation.dates,
      date = dates[date] = dates[date] || [ ];

      date.push(time);
      return obj;
}, {});
results.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(transformed, null, '\t');
```

```html
<pre id="results"></pre>
```

But if you really want to transform it to that, I'd propose grabing this transformation and map it to your proposed structure.

```js
var showtimesData = [
        {"location":"location1", "date":"31-12-2016", "time":"1:00"},
        {"location":"location1", "date":"31-12-2016", "time":"2:00"},
        {"location":"location1", "date":"01-01-2017", "time":"3:00"},
        {"location":"location1", "date":"01-01-2017", "time":"4:00"},
        {"location":"location2", "date":"31-12-2016", "time":"1:00"},
        {"location":"location2", "date":"31-12-2016", "time":"2:00"},
        {"location":"location2", "date":"01-01-2017", "time":"3:00"},
        {"location":"location2", "date":"01-01-2017", "time":"4:00"},
    ];
  
var transformed = showtimesData.reduce(function(obj, show){
  //var { location, date, time } = show; //if destructuring is available
  var location = show.location,
      date = show.date,
      time = show.time,
      objLocation = obj[location] = obj[location] || { dates : { } },
      dates = objLocation.dates,
      date = dates[date] = dates[date] || [ ];

      date.push(time);
      return obj;
}, {});

var secondTransformed = Object.keys(transformed).map(function(key){
  var dates = transformed[key].dates,
      transformedDates = Object.keys(dates).map(function(key){
          return { date : key, times : dates[key] }
      });
  return { location : key, dates : transformedDates }
});
results.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(secondTransformed, null, '\t');
```

```html
<pre id="results"></pre>
```

Although there are better ways to do this (performance wise).

Comment: Logs `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token { ` at `console`

Comment: It's the destructuring assignment, your browser doesn't support that yet.

Comment: Ok, will try at different browser

Comment: @guest271314, no worries I change it so it doesn't use it now.

Comment: fwiw, returns expected results at chromium 49 . Can include destructuring version at Answer as well ?

Comment: I'll make a note of that.

Comment: Interesting solution. How does a = b = b || {} work?

Comment: @NinaScholz, the result is an array, just not for my proposed structure (see example 2)

Comment: @chriskelly, It will first do an assigment to `b`. What `b || { }` does is use `b` if not falsy (i.e not undefined, null, 0) or create a new object if falsy. The last assignment is merely a convenience, so I don't have to type the whole path.